# Debugging PHP using Eclipse PDT or Aptana

Tags: php, ajax, debugging

Guys, has anyone been able to remotely debug a PHP Web page that uses Ajax extensively? (I'm using Zend Debugger, by the way.) When I debug, the parts of the page that are queried through Ajax HTTP GET are not shown. Is any way fix this?

Comment: This works for me in NetBeans 6.8 using Xdebug. I can set a breakpoint in the ajax target page and it stops properly when execution goes there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting up Xdebug with the firefox xdebug helper plugin, and an ide like netbeans is the way to go. If you have multiple developers using your server, use the pydbgpproxy supplied by komodo.

Netbeans is the easiest to set up debugging with by the way, its one setting in the app and a couple against the project. Just make sure you map your paths properly and tell netbeans to not open a browser window so you control the debug start from firefox.

Answer (score 2):

I like using NetBeans with Xdebug.  The firefox addon tamperdata is useful for replaying ajax requests for a debug session.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I've given up on Zend Debugger. I've installed X-debug, and not only that it properly debugs Ajax pages, but it is also much faster.

Comment: I also have had much better luck with X-debug.